# Is it the appropriate use of the Gesture Event Listener in Polymer 2?

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

```
Polymer.Gestures.addListener(googleLoginBtn, 'tap', e => loginWithGoogle(e));
Polymer.Gestures.addListener(logOutBtn, 'tap', e => logOut(e));
```

Here googleLoginBtn and logOutBtn are the ID's of the respective buttons that allow you to login and logout. I've imported all the necessary code that is required to use the Gesture Event Listener.

I'm getting this error saying that my addListener is null. What should I change in order to make it work.

Comment: How did you define `googleLoginBtn` and `logOutBtn`?

Comment: I did it the usual way I guess, `let googleLoginBtn = document.getElementById('googleLoginBtn');` and similarly for the `logOutBtn`

Comment: Have you tried doing it in Polymer way? Like `let googleLoginBtn = this.$.googleLoginBtn;`

Comment: @Ofisora I'm getting this error saying that googleLoginBtn is undefined and cannot read property.

Comment: Is is possible to post you full code by editing the question?

Comment: Here you go : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGWZoW?editors=0010

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the code you provided [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGWZoW?editors=0010):

Solution (Easy one):

```
<paper-button raised on-tap="loginWithGoogle" id="googleLoginBtn">Login 
with Google</paper-button>
```

Since you are using annotated event listener for the gesture events "tap" you can simply define function/listener `loginWithGoogle` inside class. Polymer automatically does the extra bookkeeping for gesture events when you use annotated event listeners.

Example:

```
loginWithGoogle(){
//.. Do login on tap
}
```

Another solution will be defining the gesture events on constructor or ready method inside class that extends Polymer.Element.

```
class NotesApp extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'notes-app'; }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      prop1: {
        type: String,
        value: 'notes-app'
      },
      currentUser: {
        type: String
      }
    };
  }

loginWithGoogle(e) {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      console.log(token);
      var user = result.user;
      console.log(user);
      currentUser = user.displayName;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
}

 logOut (e) {
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  alert("Signed Out!");
  }).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
});
}

////Like this////
ready(){
  super.ready();
  Polymer.Gestures.addListener(this.$.googleLoginBtn, 'tap', e => 
  loginWithGoogle(e));
  Polymer.Gestures.addListener(this.$.logOutBtn, 'tap', e => logOut(e));
}

}
```

In some cases you might need to extend class like:

```
class NotesApp extends Polymer.GestureEventListeners(Polymer.Element){...}
```